Characteristic class detecting "upward-facing" surfaces
Let $\Sigma \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smoothly embedded compact oriented surface with boundary. Let $\vec{n}: \Sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be the field of unit normal vectors associated to the orientation of $\Sigma$ via the right-hand rule. Let $\vec{z} = (0, 0, 1)$. Let $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle : \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3$ denote the standard inner product (i.e. the dot product).
We say that $\Sigma$ is upward-facing if, for all $p \in \Sigma$, we have $\langle \vec{n}_p, \vec{z} \rangle > 0$.
I am wondering if there are any known invariants of the embedding $\Sigma$ which detect the property of being upward-facing (up to something like ambient isotopy or homotopy). I know characteristic classes are some times used for this sort of thing, but am not too well-versed in that area.
Any suggestions appreciated, thanks!

This is equivalent to the condition that $\int_S dx\wedge dy >0$ for every subsurface (with boundary) $S\subset\Sigma$. Characteristic classes are definitely not local, and all you have for surfaces is the Euler class, which detects curvatureand is a topological invariant; yours most definitely is not invariant under much.

You can switch the sign with a change of basis and since your choice of coordinates matter it's not a property of the surface.

After some thought, I see that ANY such surface is upward-facing up to ambient isotopy. Leaving this comment here in case it helps someone in the future. I can give more details if anyone asks.
